# Como migrar dados entre tabelas referenciando ID?

Tags: sql-server

Possuo uma tabela chamada *Clipping* em meu banco de dados contendo dados diversos, inclusive os dados binários de uma imagem em uma coluna `varbinary(max)`. Preciso migrar apenas a coluna de dados binários pra uma outra tabela chamada *Arquivos* e referenciar o ID do *Arquivo* em uma coluna da tabela *Clipping*.

Ja tentei utilizar `OUTPUT`:

```
insert into Arquivos (ARQ_ARQUIVO)
output inserted.ARQ_ID on Clipping.ARQ_ID
select CLP_ARQUIVO from Clipping
```

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Qual é o objetivo de migrar a coluna CLP_ARQUIVO de uma tabela para outra? // Na tabela Clipping há coluna que identifique cada linha de forma única? // Conhece FILESTREAM? // Sugiro que poste mais informações sobre as tabelas Arquivos e Clipping.

Comment: @JoséDiz queremos centralizar todo os arquivos em uma unica tabela, atualmente a tabela Clipping armazena as informações e as imagens do Clipping. Queremos apenas mover as imagens para outra tabela (Arquivos) e deixar as informações na tabela Clipping. Quanto ao FILESTREAM já li sobre mas não implementei.

Comment: Como é procedimento que será executado uma única vez, e considerando-se as características da coluna a ser migrada, uma solução simples de ser implementada é através do uso de cursor. Mova um arquivo por vez, inclusive apagando o conteúdo da coluna CLP_ARQUIVO da tabela Clipping a cada movimento. // Lembre-se de efetuar backup antes de iniciar a migração.

Comment: @JoséDiz Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Acrescentei a solução cursor na resposta. É possível também solução _set-based_, mas para isso é necessário que você acrescente a estrutura das tabelas `Clipping` e `Arquivos` na definição do problema. Em específico as chaves primárias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cláusula OUTPUT adiciona linhas no destino informado; não atualiza linhas.

Como é procedimento que será executado uma única vez, e considerando-se as características da coluna a ser migrada, uma solução simples de ser implementada é através do uso de cursor.

```
-- código #1
declare Lê_Clipping cursor
     local forward_only
     for SELECT CLP_ARQUIVO
           from Clipping
           order by CLP_ID
     for update of CLP_ARQUIVO, ARQ_ID;

declare @ARQ_ID int, @CLP_ARQUIVO varbinary(max);   

Open Lê_Clipping;

FETCH NEXT 
  from Lê_Clipping
  into @CLP_ARQUIVO;

while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin

  -- copia a imagem lida para nova linha na tabela Arquivos
  INSERT into Arquivos (ARQ_ARQUIVO) 
    values (@CLP_ARQUIVO);

  -- memoriza o ID da nova linha
  set @ARQ_ID= scope_identity();

  -- insere o ID da imagem na respectiva linha da tabela Clipping
  UPDATE Clipping
    set CLP_ARQUIVO= null,
        ARQ_ID= @ARQ_ID
    where current of Lê_Clipping;

  -- lê próxima linha de Clipping
  FETCH NEXT 
    from Lê_Clipping
    into @CLP_ARQUIVO; 

  end;

CLOSE Lê_Clipping;

DEALLOCATE Lê_Clipping;
```

---

O cursor está declarado como atualizável, conforme trecho

```
for update of CLP_ARQUIVO, ARQ_ID
```

Isto funciona, desde que na tabela Clipping exista chave primária. Caso contrário o cursor é considerado somente leitura.